# (sub)sample point cloud images rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to do a simple GUI with Rviz and my kinect, I uncommented the line to use Rviz in kinect+rgbdslam.launch file:

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find rgbdslam)/launch/rviz_config.vcg" respawn="false" output="log" > </node>
```

I was "playing" with the configuration of Rviz and when I tried to add a pointscloud2 image (like enable Blue or White Display in rviz_config.vcg), but my Rviz application is freezing and I have to kill it because I cant do anything more.

I think it's because /camera/rgb/points or /camera/depth/points are sending too much datas and that's why I would like to subsampling it, by taking one image on two or even more. Does that it make sens to anyone? and is there a tutorial about rviz_config file?

Thanks for your help, I didn't find anything on this subject.

Cheers

Brioche

PS: I'm using electric on ubuntu 11.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36287/(sub)sample-point-cloud-images-rviz/) by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to throttling the topic as @Felix Endres suggested, you could use a [VoxelGrid filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Filters#VoxelGrid) to reduce the number of points in each message.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-06-12**:
I'm new in ros, so I don't understand what should I do to reduce the number of points by using VoxelGrid filter. but anyway thanks for the help

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-06-13**:
There's a tutorial that gives an example of using a VoxelGrid for downsampling: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials/VoxelGrid%20filtering

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-06-13**:
Thanks a lot, it's almost working perfectly. I'm now going to try to use octo_server.